# Windows Forms textbox that has line numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm looking for a free winforms component for an application I'm writing. I basicly need a textbox that contains line numbers in a side column. Being able to tabulate data within it would be a major plus too.

Does anyone know of a premade component that could do this?

Comment: Windows, not WIndows. Please fix. Is bugging me :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referencing [Wayne's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124975/windows-forms-textbox-that-has-line-numbers#125093), here is the relevant code. It is using GDI to draw line numbers next to the text box.

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()

    'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.SelectionChanged
    FindLine()
    Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub FindLine()
    Dim intChar As Integer

    intChar = RichTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(New Point(0, 0))
    intLine = RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(intChar)
End Sub

Private Sub DrawLines(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal intLine As Integer)
    Dim intCounter As Integer, intY As Integer

    g.Clear(Color.Black)

    intCounter = intLine + 1
    intY = 2
    Do
        g.DrawString(intCounter.ToString(), Font, Brushes.White, 3, intY)
        intCounter += 1

        intY += Font.Height + 1
        If intY > ClientRectangle.Height - 15 Then Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    DrawLines(e.Graphics, intLine)
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_VScroll(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.VScroll
    FindLine()
    Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_UserScroll() Handles RichTextBox1.UserScroll
    FindLine()
    Invalidate()
End Sub
```

The RichTextBox is overridden like this:

```
Public Class UserControl1
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox

Public Event UserScroll()

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = &H115 Then
        RaiseEvent UserScroll()
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
End Class
```

(Code by divil on the xtremedotnettalk.com forum.)

Comment: is this doable in C# as well?

Comment: yes, http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ should get you started. if you get it working you should post it as an answer as a resource for others.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [SharpDevelop](https://github.com/icsharpcode) C# compiler/IDE source code. They have a sophisticated text box with line numbers. You could look at the source, figure out what they're doing, and then implement it yourself.

Here's a sample of what I'm referencing:
[image]
<sub>(source: [sharpdevelop.net](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/photos/mattward/images/original/FeatureTourQuickClassBrowser.aspx))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

There is a project with code available at http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?s=&threadid=49661&highlight=RichTextBox.

You can log into the site to download the zip file with the user/pass: bugmenot/bugmenot

Comment: Deprecated user/pass... Consider moving to 'unprotected' storage? :-/

Comment: Sorry.. wasn't my project and the answer was from 5 years ago.  However, it looks like the top answer grabbed the relevant code and posted it above.

Answer (score 2):

There is a source code editing component in CodePlex for .net,
http://www.codeplex.com/ScintillaNET

Answer (score 2):

Here's some C# code to do this.  It's based on the code from xtremedotnettalk.com referenced by Wayne.  I've made some changes to make it actually display the editor text, which the original didn't do.  But, to be fair, the original code author did mention it needed work.

Here's the code (NumberedTextBox.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NumberedTextBoxLib {
  public partial class NumberedTextBox : UserControl {
    private int lineIndex = 0;

    new public String Text {
      get {
        return editBox.Text;
      }
      set {
        editBox.Text = value;
      }
    }

    public NumberedTextBox() {
      InitializeComponent();
      SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
      SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
      SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
      SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
      editBox.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(selectionChanged);
      editBox.VScroll += new EventHandler(OnVScroll);
    }

    private void selectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs args) {
      FindLine();
      Invalidate();
    }

    private void FindLine() {
      int charIndex = editBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(0, 0));
      lineIndex = editBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(charIndex);
    }

    private void DrawLines(Graphics g) {
      int counter, y;
      g.Clear(BackColor);
      counter = lineIndex + 1;
      y = 2;
      int max = 0;
      while (y < ClientRectangle.Height - 15) {
        SizeF size = g.MeasureString(counter.ToString(), Font);
        g.DrawString(counter.ToString(), Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), new Point(3, y));
        counter++;
        y += (int)size.Height;
        if (max < size.Width) {
          max = (int) size.Width;
        }
      }
      max += 6;
      editBox.Location = new Point(max, 0);
      editBox.Size = new Size(ClientRectangle.Width - max, ClientRectangle.Height);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
      DrawLines(e.Graphics);
      e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(50, 0);
      editBox.Invalidate();
      base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    ///Redraw the numbers when the editor is scrolled vertically
    private void OnVScroll(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      FindLine();
      Invalidate();
    }

  }
}
```

And here is the Visual Studio designer code (NumberedTextBox.Designer.cs)

```
namespace NumberedTextBoxLib {
  partial class NumberedTextBox {
    /// Required designer variable.
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
      if (disposing && (components != null)) {
        components.Dispose();
      }
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    private void InitializeComponent() {
      this.editBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
      this.SuspendLayout();
      // 
      // editBox
      // 
      this.editBox.AcceptsTab = true;
      this.editBox.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles) ((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                  | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                  | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
      this.editBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(27, 3);
      this.editBox.Name = "editBox";
      this.editBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(122, 117);
      this.editBox.TabIndex = 0;
      this.editBox.Text = "";
      this.editBox.WordWrap = false;
      // 
      // NumberedTextBox
      // 
      this.Controls.Add(this.editBox);
      this.Name = "NumberedTextBox";
      this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 123);
      this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox editBox;
  }
}
```

Comment: Old, but it should use `editBox.Font` instead of `Font` everywhere, and it would be better to get the position of a number label by doing so: 

`y = editBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(editBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(counter - 1));`

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on the Font size, I used "Courier New, 9pt, style=bold"

- Added fix for smooth scrolling, (not line by line)
- Added fix for big files, when scroll value is over 16bit.

**NumberedTextBox.cs**

```
public partial class NumberedTextBox : UserControl
{
    private int _lines = 0;

    [Browsable(true), 
        EditorAttribute("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design","System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor")]
    new public String Text
    {
        get
        {
            return editBox.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            editBox.Text = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private Color _lineNumberColor = Color.LightSeaGreen;

    [Browsable(true), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "LightSeaGreen")]
    public Color LineNumberColor {
        get{
            return _lineNumberColor;
        }
        set
        {
            _lineNumberColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public NumberedTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        editBox.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(selectionChanged);
        editBox.VScroll += new EventHandler(OnVScroll);
    }

    private void selectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void DrawLines(Graphics g)
    {
        g.Clear(BackColor);
        int y = - editBox.ScrollPos.Y;
        for (var i = 1; i < _lines + 1; i++)
        {
            var size = g.MeasureString(i.ToString(), Font);
            g.DrawString(i.ToString(), Font, new SolidBrush(LineNumberColor), new Point(3, y));
            y += Font.Height + 2;
        }
        var max = (int)g.MeasureString((_lines + 1).ToString(), Font).Width + 6;
        editBox.Location = new Point(max, 0);
        editBox.Size = new Size(ClientRectangle.Width - max, ClientRectangle.Height);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        _lines = editBox.Lines.Count();
        DrawLines(e.Graphics);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(50, 0);
        editBox.Invalidate();
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    private void OnVScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    public void Select(int start, int length)
    {
        editBox.Select(start, length);
    }

    public void ScrollToCaret()
    {
        editBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }

    private void editBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }
}

public class RichTextBoxEx : System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
{
    private double _Yfactor = 1.0d;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, Int32 wParam, ref Point lParam);

    private enum WindowsMessages
    {
        WM_USER = 0x400,
        EM_GETSCROLLPOS = WM_USER + 221,
        EM_SETSCROLLPOS = WM_USER + 222
    }

    public Point ScrollPos
    {
        get
        {
            var scrollPoint = new Point();
            SendMessage(this.Handle, (int)WindowsMessages.EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref scrollPoint);
            return scrollPoint;
        }
        set
        {
            var original = value;
            if (original.Y < 0)
                original.Y = 0;
            if (original.X < 0)
                original.X = 0;

            var factored = value;
            factored.Y = (int)((double)original.Y * _Yfactor);

            var result = value;

            SendMessage(this.Handle, (int)WindowsMessages.EM_SETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref factored);
            SendMessage(this.Handle, (int)WindowsMessages.EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref result);

            var loopcount = 0;
            var maxloop = 100;
            while (result.Y != original.Y)
            {
                // Adjust the input.
                if (result.Y > original.Y)
                    factored.Y -= (result.Y - original.Y) / 2 - 1;
                else if (result.Y < original.Y)
                    factored.Y += (original.Y - result.Y) / 2 + 1;

                // test the new input.
                SendMessage(this.Handle, (int)WindowsMessages.EM_SETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref factored);
                SendMessage(this.Handle, (int)WindowsMessages.EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref result);

                // save new factor, test for exit.
                loopcount++;
                if (loopcount >= maxloop || result.Y == original.Y)
                {
                    _Yfactor = (double)factored.Y / (double)original.Y;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NumberedTextBox.Designer.cs**

```
partial class NumberedTextBox
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.editBox = new WebTools.Controls.RichTextBoxEx();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // editBox
        // 
        this.editBox.AcceptsTab = true;
        this.editBox.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.editBox.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
        this.editBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(27, 3);
        this.editBox.Name = "editBox";
        this.editBox.ScrollPos = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.editBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 115);
        this.editBox.TabIndex = 0;
        this.editBox.Text = "";
        this.editBox.WordWrap = false;
        this.editBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.editBox_TextChanged);
        // 
        // NumberedTextBox
        // 
        this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Controls.Add(this.editBox);
        this.Name = "NumberedTextBox";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 121);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    private RichTextBoxEx editBox;

    #endregion
}
```